# How to realize sequent addition of elements to vector, sorting them before to insert?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, vector, stl

I tried to write programm inserting elements into a vector, sorting them in alphabetical order. The element before to be inserted compares with another ones till it more than element already inserted. After it was assumed to add compared element using `.insert()`. I want to realize it without using sort algorithmes.

```
std::string name;
std::vector<std::string> students;
std::vector<std::string>::iterator beg = students.begin();
  while (std::cin>>name){
        for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator e = students.end() ; beg !=e ; ) {
            if (!name.compare(*beg))
            {
                students.insert(beg, name);
                break;
            }
            else
                beg++;      
         }
    }
```

To avoid invalidate of iterator pointed to the last element I renew it each iteration. 
The problem is after this part of code I check the vector but it's empty.

Comment: The shown code clearly does not "renew it each iteration", despite your claim. Which part of the shown code resets the `beg` iterator correctly, on each iteration? Undefined behavior.

Comment: Realy, I'll change it

Comment: Also, `compare()` is not a boolean function, and does not work the way you think it works. Your comparison is wrong.

Comment: nitpick on wording: by definition you cannot sort without using an algorithm. Any code that gets you the vector sorted is an implementation of an algorithm. I guess you meant no standard algorithm from `<algorithm>`. But why? Also note that sorting after each single `insert` is not very efficient. Better take all input, then sort

Comment: @Konstantin You tagged this as `algorithm`, so here goes -- You should be using `std::lower_bound` or `std::upper_bound`.  The `vector` is sorted already, so to insert an item into a sorted vector is done more efficiently by binary searching where the item should go, not starting from the beginning and comparing each element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This comparison

```
if (!name.compare(*beg))
```

does not make sense. It checks only that two strings are equal.

Consider for example the following code snippet

```
std::string s1 = "one";
std::string s2 = "one";
std::cout << !s1.compare( s2 ) << '\n';
```

Its output is `1`. It means that the two objects are equal.

Moreover the for loop can ends without finding the position where a string can be inserted for example when initially the vector is empty.

And this statement

```
std::vector<std::string>::iterator beg = students.begin();
```

must be inside the outer while loop. That is the iterator shall be initialized anew in each iteration of the loop.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the inner loop can be implemented.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

void insert( std::vector<std::string> &v, const std::string &s )
{
    auto it = std::begin( v );

    while (  it != std::end( v ) && not( s < *it ) ) ++it;

    v.insert( it, s );
}

int main() 
{
    std::string names[] = { "One", "Two", "Three" };
    std::vector<std::string> v;

    for ( const auto &s : names )
    {
        insert( v, s );
    }


    for ( const auto &s : v ) std::cout << s << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
One Three Two
```

That is the strings are inserted in the ascending order.

Relative to your code snippet the loops can look like

```
while ( std::cin >> name )
{
    auto it = std::begin( students ); // or students.begin()

    while (  it != std::end( students ) && not( name < *it ) ) ++it;

    students.insert( it, name );
}
```

Also instead of the inner while loop you could use the standard algorithm `std::find_if`. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

//...

while ( std::cin >> name )
{
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    auto it = std::find_if( std::begin( students ), std::end( students ), 
                            std::bind( std::greater_equal<>(), _1, name ) );

    students.insert( it, name );
}
```

Comment: That was really complete answer) But how can we use `std::end( v )` in this part of code `void insert( std::vector<std::string> &v, const std::string &s )
{
    auto it = std::begin( v );

    while (  it != std::end( v ) && not( s < *it ) ) ++it;

    v.insert( it, s );
}` if we chande 'end' iterator each iteration? I must don't understand something

Comment: @Konstantin Starting from the C++ 11 there are general functions std::begin and std::end declared in the header <iterator> that allows to apply them to any standard container or an array.

Comment: I meant after `insert()` the `end` iterator changed, didn't it? But in the next iteration you used the same `end`

Comment: @Konstantin As it is a function then the end iterator is calculated anew using the function.

Answer (score 1):

For an empty vector `begin` and `end` are the same, hence you never insert anything.

It is not clear why you do not want to use a sorting algorithm, hence I would propose the following:

```
std::string name;
std::vector<std::string> students;
while (std::cin>>name){
    students.push_back(name);
}
std::sort(students.begin(),students.end());
```

Alternatively, replace the last line with your favourite sorting routine.